# Getting last item in a recursive Laravel relationship

Tags: php, laravel

I have a `manager()` relationship in my User model which is recursive so I can get the manager of the user, the manager of the manager and so on. This eventually will lead to a manager who is a Director.

```
User
   Manager
     Their Manager
        Their Manager
           Director
```

My question is, how do I extract the Director? I've tried `user->manager->first()` and `user->manager->latest()->first()` amongst other but none seem to return the desired result.

Below is the relation code in my `User` model:

```
public function manager()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(__CLASS__, 'line_manager_id')->with('manager');
}
```

Comment: Who is a director? A user with no manager ? Or the highest/last user in **every** chain?

Comment: Correct, they will always be the last person in a manager chain

Comment: Just iterate though the managers until you hit a director?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this method to your user model, then call `$user->getDirector();`

```
public function getDirector()
{
    if ($this->manager) {
      return $this->manager->getDirector();
    }

    return $this;
}
```